# How table was created in SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, metadata

What I need to find is the procedure of recreating some table, what data sources were used, which scripts if any &c. So is it possible to differentiate somehow, maybe in system views or similar, if the table was created manually or by query and if the data was imported from external data or from already existing table/view in the database? I already know who created and when. I’ve pretty much screened whole database without results and now I am looking for hints in metadata.

Comment: There is no such metadata. Unlike stored procedures, tables are stored only as their internal representations. The script(s) that created them are not recorded anywhere. From the engine's point of view, there is no way to "create a table manually" -- everything always ultimately happens with a (possibly generated) `CREATE TABLE` statement. (Or `SELECT INTO`, if you want to get pedantic.)

Comment: There is no way to know the source of what created a table. Think about this...in the end it is all just executing a sql script. SSMS just creates a script and executes it for you.

Comment: You can find the create table statement by using third party tools like RedGate. Another way you can find when you have associated database project into your solution. In these two cases you can search for create table 'TableName'.

Comment: On a side note, if you want to monitor CREATE TABLE events going forward, you may want to take a look at [DDL Triggers](http://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2016/07/SQL-Server-Event-Handling-DDL-Events.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the table was created recently, you can glean information from the default trace.  The query below will list object created and altered events.  The default trace is a rollover trace so forensic information will be limited based on activity.

```
SELECT  
     trace.DatabaseName
    ,trace.ObjectName
    ,te.name AS EventName
    ,tsv.subclass_name
    ,trace.EventClass
    ,trace.EventSubClass
    ,trace.StartTime
    ,trace.EndTime
    ,trace.NTDomainName
    ,trace.NTUserName
    ,trace.HostName
    ,trace.ApplicationName
    ,trace.Spid
FROM (SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(path), 1, CHARINDEX(N'\', REVERSE(path)), '')) + N'\Log.trc' AS path
    FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1) AS default_trace_path
CROSS APPLY fn_trace_gettable(default_trace_path.path, DEFAULT) AS trace
JOIN sys.trace_events AS te ON 
    trace.EventClass=te.trace_event_id
JOIN sys.trace_subclass_values AS tsv ON
    tsv.trace_event_id = EventClass
    AND tsv.subclass_value = trace.EventSubClass
WHERE te.name IN(N'Object:Altered', N'Object:Created')
    AND tsv.subclass_name = 'Commit'
ORDER BY trace.StartTime;
```